# Desplegar app de iOS en macOS virtualizado

Tags: ios, macos, programación-móvil, deployment, virtualización

Buen día, mi duda no es técnica sino simplemente relacionada a asuntos legales. Estoy trabajando con el stack Mysql, nodejs, dart y flutter para una aplicación móvil multiplataforma, pero me preguntaba si puedo subirla a iOS desde una máquina virtual, o si por otro lado tendría inconvenientes con eso, y en caso de ser así qué me recomendarían en su lugar.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si en la máquina virtual puedes instalar los certificados de Apple de Developer y Producción junto con los Perfiles de tu cuenta y que no tengas errores en Xcode; entonces no habría inconveniente.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: Lamentablemente el sitio no esta dirigido para aclarar temas legales que pueden estar basados en la opinion del profesional al que consultes o en la legislacion en el pais en el que te encuentras o el pais en donde se desplegara la aplicacion.